# SDWebImageDataSource in KTPhotoBrowser --iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4

I am using `KTPhotoBrowser` in order to display images parsed from a server. 
Also, I am sharing the image by using Share kit. The sharing works fine when I am using the `PhotoDataSource` `NSObject` class in the `KTPhotoBrowser`.

However, if I use `SDWebImageDataSource`  `NSObject` class to share the images by Share kit, it crashes when I press the action sheet button saying

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception NSInvalidArgumentException, reason:
>
> `->[SDWebImageDataSource imageAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8682e10`

I am able to display the image in the scroll view.

I have used the following code in when I press the action sheet. In the `KTPhotoScrollViewController` class.

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

  if (buttonIndex == actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex) return;

  NSDictionary *table = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"SHKTwitter", @"Twitter", @"SHKFacebook", @"Facebook", @"SHKMail", SHKLocalizedString(@"Email", nil), nil];
  NSString *sharersName = [actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
  Class SharersClass = NSClassFromString([table objectForKey:sharersName]);

  [table release];

  NSLog(@"dataaaasrc-- %@",dataSource_);
  UIImage *image = [dataSource_ imageAtIndex:currentIndex_];
  SHKItem *item = [SHKItem image:image title:@"Look at this picture!"];

  [SharersClass performSelector:@selector(shareItem:) withObject:item];      
}
```

In the NSLog I got the following:

```
dataaaasrc--SDWebImageDataSource: 0x8682e10 //betwn lessthan and greater than symbols

-[SDWebImageDataSource imageAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8682e10

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SDWebImageDataSource imageAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8682e10'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make a "Save Image" button, the same place where you want your sharekit button by using some code from a sample that comes with KTPhotoBrowser.
(I looked in the TabBarSample with FlickrSample)

In SDWebImageDataSource.m I added this:

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithURLString:(NSString *)string {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    return image;
}

- (UIImage *)imageSourceAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    NSArray *imageUrls = [images_ objectAtIndex:index];
    NSString *url = [imageUrls objectAtIndex:FULL_SIZE_INDEX];

    return [self imageWithURLString:url];
}
```

In KTPhotoBrowserDataSource.h:

```
- (UIImage *)imageSourceAtIndex:(NSInteger)index;
```

Then you can make your call like this:

```
UIImage *image = [dataSource_ imageSourceAtIndex:currentIndex_];
```